# Exampe of best practice MVC Module in DotNetNuke 9

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

Can anyone point my in the right direction? I am looking for what would be considered best practice MVC flavor DNN9 module and/or tutorial?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris Hammond's DNN Module Templates include an MVC module.  See christoc.com or the DNN store.

Comment: I support this message